# Regarding to get refrence of IDot11AdHocManager Interface of COM WiFi AdHoc manager Interface

Tags: c++, windows, com, network-programming

I am Trying to create AdHoc connection and for this i am using AdHoc wifi Interface provided by Microsoft.
I have written code :-

```
    IDot11AdHocManager *pIAdHocMng = NULL ;
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Dot11AdHocManager,NULL,CLSCTX_INPROC_HANDLER ,IID_IDot11AdHocManager ,(void**)pIAdHocMng); 
if(hr == S_OK)
        printf("CreateNetwork Method success due to following reason :\n %ld",hr) ;
else 
        printf("CreateNetwork Method fail due to following reason : %ld \n ",hr) ;

getch();

CoUninitialize();
```

But it will not return reference of Dot11AdHocManager it will return error and NULL value please help me to get the reference of Dot11AdHocManager Interface so i can use it method which help me to create the AdHoc Network

Comment: Which error value specifically does it return?

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be (the last parameter is changed):

```
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Dot11AdHocManager,NULL,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IID_IDot11AdHocManager ,(void**) &pIAdHocMng);
```